# Do I need to explicitly grant various internet/network Manifest permissions for these conditions?

Tags: android, networking, permissions, admob, android-manifest

In my app I have the following relevant components:

-My app uses Google AdMob advertisement banners

-My app allows you to import / export data using the media Intent chooser, which may involve letting the user choose some online service such as Gmail, Google Drive, etc.

-My app occasionally displays hyperlinks and buttons in certain places that opens the user's browser and goes to the designated site.

Does any of this **require** special permission in the Manifest?

Comment: Yes, AdMob will fetch ads from internet, so you'll need internet permission. That's all.

Comment: @Ekalips More specifically, `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` or something else? Do I need "network state" for this or anything else?

Comment: Does this permission apply to AdMob or all three parts of my post?

Comment: Yes, `android.permission.INTERNET`. And yes, it's for all 3 parts of your post. Only AdMob requires special permissions.

Comment: @Ekalips I am confused, then. AdMob requires special permissions, and yet the permission applies to all three parts?

Comment: You have only one manifest file for your app. And you need to place your permissions in apps manifest. So if one of the components require network permission - all will receive it, because they share one manifest. This is not applied if you use instant apps, as far as I know all instant app parts require separate manifests.

Comment: @Ekalips What I mean though is which of the three components require "special permissions" and which do not require explicit permission in the manifest, etc. If I were to omit the internet permission, which of the three would encounter issues?

Comment: If you omit internet permission only AdMob will lead you to trouble. And oh, maybe I was wrong, and 2nd point in your list require permission too. Refer to @RoodrigoGontijo answer

Comment: Oi obviously you will need internet permission for AdMob, ads can't display without internet. For the other 2 you will not need permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use the following permission in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: For which component does this permission apply? Just AdMob? or all three?

Comment: It applies to all three

Comment: It only applies to AdMob, while internet access in the other 2 options is achieved from other apps.

Answer (score 4):

As I couldn't find a proper answer here (existing are contradicting), I did my home work and tested with a real app.

- AdMob, when adding the dependency to the SDK, both INTERNET and READ_NETWORK_STATE permissions are automatically added to the Manifest of the generated or built APK. I have no INTERNET permission anywhere in my project, but the gerenated APK does. Removing the SDK, the permission is gone.
- Loading content from other apps does not require INTERNET permission, even if those apps are receiving the content from internet.
- Opening URL in a device's browser does not require INTERNET either, it's the browser which needs it.

To answer the OP, one does not need to add any special permission in Manifest to do any of the 3 above mentioned features.

However note that INTERNET permission is automatically added by the dependency on AdMob's SDK.

Answer (score 1):

No you don't need to. 
Check out this quick start guide and see there is no mention of adding those permissions.
https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start

I have a similar app running on android P and no permissions are required. So cheers.
Also do remember that you need to use dummy ID while testing ad mobs.

Comment: Please add sone description

Comment: While you don't have to add the permission explicitly, the SDK does it for you along with READ_NETWORK_STATE.

Answer (score 0):

**-My app uses Google AdMob advertisement banners** - In the official site of AdMob, nothing related to the internet permission, as you can see [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/quick-start)

**-My app allows you to import / export data using the media Intent chooser, which may involve letting the user choose some online service such as Gmail, Google Drive, etc.** if you want to import data, you need to set the permission!

**-My app occasionally displays hyperlinks and buttons in certain places that opens the user's browser and goes to the designated site.** - I guess it does not need internet permission, but i´m not shure.

Comment: I don't see anywhere in that AdMob link that talks about permissions?

Comment: In the official site i couldn´t see anything.
The only way you will know if at least one of the three components requires the internet permission is testing. If your app crashes due SecurityException, you just put the permission there.